# Passing a condition into Func<bool> of a Tuple<string, string, Func<bool>>

Tags: c#, properties, tuples

I am trying to create a list of tuples with properties and conditions for their validation. So I had this idea in mind:

```
List<Tuple<string, string, Func<bool>>> properties = new List<Tuple<string, 
                                                                    string,
                                                                    Func<bool>>> 
{
    Tuple.Create(FirstName, "User first name is required", ???),
};
...
```

How can I pass expression of type (FirstName == null) as Func ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this (using a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)):

```
var properties = new List<Tuple<string, string, Func<bool>>> 
{
    Tuple.Create<string, string, Func<bool>>(
                 FirstName, 
                 "User first name is required",
                 () => FirstName == null),
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
List<Tuple<string, string, Func<bool>>> properties = new List<Tuple<string, string, Func<bool>>> 
{
    Tuple.Create(FirstName, "User first name is required", new Func<bool>(() => FirstName == null)),
};
```

Note that there are some limitatons to type inference for lambda expressions... for this reason the `new Func<bool>` way of building a delegate is used.

Alternatives:

```
Tuple.Create(FirstName, "User first name is required", (Func<bool>)(() => FirstName == null)),
Tuple.Create<string, string, Func<bool>>(FirstName, "User first name is required", () => FirstName == null),
new Tuple<string, string, Func<bool>>(FirstName, "User first name is required", () => FirstName == null),
```

In the end you have to repeate the `Func<bool>` somewhere.